# What does it mean that the normalized power of a received equals one?

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications

I have read in that lecture, page 2, [here](http://www.comlab.hut.fi/studies/3280/Lectures/ARTM_equalize_1_ISI.pdf) that,  the symbols are independent, and normalized to have power 1, which means $E(x x^H) = I$ .. what does that mean? could you please explain that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mundane words: the concept is very close to that of orthogonality. For two components of $x$, say  $x_i$ and  $x_j$, if they are different ($i \neq j)$, the average outcome of their product is zero (or $E(x_i x_j^H)  =0$). If   $i = j$, one assumes that the energy is normalized to one (or $E(x_i x_i^H)  =1$).

Resultingly, the product matrix is a unit matrix: one for the diagonal ($i = j$), and zero outside.